# Division results from SQL to separate List <int>

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I get the result from a MySQL table as below. 
The result of data each time is different and I need to group it to separate new List < int >. 
The list of data in a DataTable:

```
id_task id_supplier id_source_ps
1   77  3
2   71  3
3   77  1
4   77  2
5   72  3
6   72  2
7   77  3
8   72  3
9   71  1
10  72  3
```

The condition of grouping id_task to the new list is the same id_supplier and id_source_ps!

What method (LINQ?) Use to get the result - as in this example - seven of new List < int >

```
name of list    id_task_in
group1  9
group2  2
group3  6
group4  5,8,10
group5  3
group6  4
group7  1,7
```

Comment: Your result type is not a List<int>.  It's a List<string>.  Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `GroupBy`. You need to `GroupBy` your keys then `Select` your result. Here is an example using your data --

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { task = 1, supplier = 77, source = 3 },
            new Item { task = 2, supplier = 71, source = 3 },
            new Item { task = 3, supplier = 77, source = 1 },
            new Item { task = 4, supplier = 77, source = 2 },
            new Item { task = 5, supplier = 72, source = 3 },
            new Item { task = 6, supplier = 72, source = 2 },
            new Item { task = 7, supplier = 77, source = 3 },
            new Item { task = 8, supplier = 72, source = 3 },
            new Item { task = 9, supplier = 71, source = 1 },
            new Item { task = 10, supplier = 72, source = 3 }
        };

        var groupBy = 
            list
            .GroupBy(x => new { first = x.source, second = x.supplier})
            .Select(x => new { name = x.Key, items = x.Count() });

        foreach (var g in groupBy)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(g);
        }        
    }        
}

public class Item
{
    public int task;
    public int supplier;
    public int source;
}
```

This prints

```
{ name = { first = 3, second = 77 }, items = 2 }
{ name = { first = 3, second = 71 }, items = 1 }
{ name = { first = 1, second = 77 }, items = 1 }
{ name = { first = 2, second = 77 }, items = 1 }
{ name = { first = 3, second = 72 }, items = 3 }
{ name = { first = 2, second = 72 }, items = 1 }
{ name = { first = 1, second = 71 }, items = 1 }
```

You can use this example as your starting point. To accomplish what you need, just change the `.Count()` to `.Aggregate()` so it returns a list of the task id's instead of the number of task ids. You can also change the key to match "group 1" "group 2" if you'd like but you will need to come up with some standard way to number each group (e.g., `"group"+(index+1).ToString())`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Tom's answer:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { task = 1, supplier = 77, source = 3 },
        new Item { task = 2, supplier = 71, source = 3 },
        new Item { task = 3, supplier = 77, source = 1 },
        new Item { task = 4, supplier = 77, source = 2 },
        new Item { task = 5, supplier = 72, source = 3 },
        new Item { task = 6, supplier = 72, source = 2 },
        new Item { task = 7, supplier = 77, source = 3 },
        new Item { task = 8, supplier = 72, source = 3 },
        new Item { task = 9, supplier = 71, source = 1 },
        new Item { task = 10, supplier = 72, source = 3 }
    };

    var groupBy = list.GroupBy(x => new { first = x.supplier, second = x.source})
      .OrderBy(x=>x.Key.first).ThenBy(x=>x.Key.second)
      .Select((x,i) => new { name = "group"+(i+1), items = x.Select(y=>y.task) });

    foreach (var g in groupBy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",g.name,String.Join(",",g.items.Select(x=>x.ToString())));
    }        
}        

public class Item
{
    public int task;
    public int supplier;
    public int source;
}
```

will return:

```
group1 9
group2 2
group3 6
group4 5,8,10
group5 3
group6 4
group7 1,7
```

I left the final output as a `IEnumerable<string,IEnumerable<int>>` because I would usually prefer it that way.  You can easily move the string.join to the select if you would prefer to have it a `IEnumerable<string,string>` instead.